# How to generate a list with the content at a particular position from a tuple removed?

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

```
>>> x=('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if i != 2]
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

I have the above tuple with 4 elements. I want to generate an array with the 3rd element in the tuple removed.

Is this the most succinct and efficient way to express this operation?

Comment: You are creating a `list`, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use slice notation to do so.

```py
>>> x = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
>>> result = list(x[:2] + x[3:])
>>> print(result)
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

At such a small scale, the difference in performance would be insignificant, but if we really want to measure it.

```py
import timeit


stmt_range = """
x = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
result = [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if i != 2]
"""


stmt_slice = """
x = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
result = list(x[:2] + x[3:])
"""

print(min(timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_range).repeat(7, 100000)))
print(min(timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_slice).repeat(7, 100000)))
```

Outputs

```
0.041514699998515425
0.0190705999993952
```

So the use of slice notation would be slightly faster.

Comment: In terms of efficiency, which one is better? This way or list comprehension?

Comment: I've added some additional details to my answer. TL; DR: it's list comprehension.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not completely familiar with benchmarking in Python. Do you know a better way?

Comment: @AntoineDelia: Take a look at the `timeit` module.

Comment: At the very very least, don't use `time()` but `perf_counter()`, at least for something that short. But yes, `timeit` is better anyway. [Demo](https://tio.run/##TVDRaoQwEHzPV0yFw8SGa085aD38khCKp7ENaAwxB/brbRKPu@ZhAzO7Mztrf/3PbKoP67ZtcPMEryelPfRkZ@fhlFWtJ2RR/mbRIF9DoVmbcWTXWLpY@ozlhHRzr5ZACwIgF6vQEsPsoKENXGu@FR2VoStj0ENAXxqUMuepe9SLp6uoS4lXrKKqJbszokgw39FHf/DZZ9gF49HOlpbsHxem5AW9GjGKZCKJuU1X5QJ3ei@KMyFqVR1NuRghcc@v554Vq6NUWj/GikyKt8Px@aA0aUP3C9HIciQ5jt2q2b8Q9@2OPIat08bT/HA@ngaYBTkOoB4FTuqT8WTFyLORbdsf).

Comment: Thanks for the info on that! I've tried to update the answer by leveraging the `timeit` module. Hopefully that's the correct way to use it. Feel free to point any weird use of it!

Comment: My bad, mixed the `setup` with the `stmt`. I think it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the tuple to a list and then use the pop method. This avoids iteration and you can even make it a function.

```py
def remove(tup, idx):
    l = list(tup)
    l.pop(idx)
    return l
```

This is my first time using the timeit module, but here is what I got.

```py
import timeit

x = tuple([i for i in range(10000)])

def myfunc (tup, idx):
    l = list(tup)
    l.pop(idx)
    return l

def shadow(tup, idx):
    l = list(tup)
    del l[idx]
    return l

print("juanpa.arrivillaga")
print(timeit.timeit("[e for i,e in enumerate(x) if i != 2]", setup = "from __main__ import x", number=10000))

print("Antoine Delia")
print(timeit.timeit("list(x[:2] + x[3:])", setup = "from __main__ import x", number=10000))

print("My solution")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="myfunc(x,2)", setup = "from __main__ import myfunc, x", number=10000))

print("ShadowRanger")
print(timeit.timeit(stmt="shadow(x,2)", setup = "from __main__ import shadow, x", number=10000))
```

Output:

```
juanpa.arrivillaga
9.834354800000256
Antoine Delia
2.695629099999678
My solution
0.6217948999997134
ShadowRanger
0.6193107999997665
```

Comment: So this is more efficient in terms of runtime?

Comment: Since you don't need the value, it should be *slightly* more efficient to do `del l[idx]` instead of `l.pop(idx)`.

Comment: @user1424739: In theory, this solution might seem slower (it has to do two `O(n)` operations, one to convert from `tuple` to `list`, and a second to remove the offending value). In practice, it's likely faster in most cases (it pushes more work below the interpreter layer, and at least in the CPython reference interpreter, the overhead of bytecode execution is significantly higher than the overhead of a couple operations pushed to the C level). For a small `tuple`, it's irrelevant though; only matters if the input is large *and* you're performing this work a lot.

Comment: So you think you have something thousands of times faster than juanpa? Gonna downvote now, then read the code :-P (edit: ah drat, daily vote limit reached)

Comment: Marcus: You're misusing the `timeit` for timing your own solution; you're timing the work to redefine your own function over and over, not the time to do anything with it. Define `remove`  normally (not as a string), add `from __main__ import remove` to the `setup`, and have the snippet be the string `"remove(x, 2)"`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger turns out you win :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think not the compilation but the definition.

Comment: How do I fix this??

Comment: @KellyBundy: True, misspoke. `timeit` compiles the snippet once, and executes it (which in this case just means redefining the function) over and over, and once compiled, the time to redefine it is trivial. Marcus, I edited the fixes needed into my previous comment.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think you also misspoke and should've said *"only matters if the input is large **or** you're performing this work a lot"* :-P. The speed relative speed differences are [quite high](https://tio.run/##TVDRaoQwEHzPV0yFw8SGa085aD38khCKp7ENaAwxB/brbRKPu@ZhAzO7Mztrf/3PbKoP67ZtcPMEryelPfRkZ@fhlFWtJ2RR/mbRIF9DoVmbcWTXWLpY@ozlhHRzr5ZACwIgF6vQEsPsoKENXGu@FR2VoStj0ENAXxqUMuepe9SLp6uoS4lXrKKqJbszokgw39FHf/DZZ9gF49HOlpbsHxem5AW9GjGKZCKJuU1X5QJ3ei@KMyFqVR1NuRghcc@v554Vq6NUWj/GikyKt8Px@aA0aUP3C9HIciQ5jt2q2b8Q9@2OPIat08bT/HA@ngaYBTkOoB4FTuqT8WTFyLORbdsf) for this small tuple already.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Calling `remove(x, 2)` puts them at an unfair disadvantage, btw (function call overhead and variable for `2`).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Nah. If I'm going to use "or", it'd need to be "ridiculously huge or you're performing this work an insane number of times (to the point where I suspect you have an XY problem and should be doing something else in the first place)". :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy: The use of a variable vs. literal doesn't really matter as long as both are locals (`LOAD_FAST` and `LOAD_CONST` are effectively identical on performance costs; they both devolve to simple C array lookup). The function call overhead I consider a reasonable expense though; if the code requires multiple lines to do something, and that thing is best described with a name to make code more self-documenting, it's fair to compare one-liners outside functions to multi-liners in a function. They can always time the unwrapped form too, but it's hard to explain how in a comment.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I mean `shadow(x,2)` vs `shadow(x)` (and hardcoded `2` inside the function), i.e., extra overhead of passing the value.